# How to calculate the value of $10^{\log_{10}(-1)}$?

Tags: logarithms

How to calculate the value of $10^{\log_{10}(-1)}$? Initially I assumed $10^{\log_{10}(-1)}=-1$ due to $10^{\log_{10}(x)}=x$. However, I'm unsure if this is true for negative numbers or only valid for $x>0$.

Thank you

Comment: You can't take logarithms of negative numbers, unless you're allowed to use complex numbers. $e^{k\pi i}=-1$, where $k$ is an odd integer.

Comment: Before you can calculate $10^{\log_{10}(-1)}$, you have to decide what $\log_{10}(-1)$ means (if anything).

Comment: What is the source of this problem?  Is it something that you thought of on your own, or is it a problem from an Analysis book?  If the latter, does the book involve Real Analysis (only), or does the book involve/include Complex Analysis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logarithm of a negative real number [can be defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Complex_logarithm) as some comlpex number.  However, the rules are bit more contrived, e.g. the logarithm laws like
$$\log (ab) = \log a  + \log b$$
to which you are familiar from real analysis now only holds modulo some constant, and there is more than one meaningful way (actually infinitely many ways) of specifying values for $\log$.

The reason is Euler's identity
$$e^{2\pi i}= 1\tag{1}$$
where $e$ is Euler's Number and $i$ is the Imaginary Unit that satisfies $i^2=-1$.

Now suppose a number $z\in\Bbb C$ in the complex plane is given in [polar form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Complex_numbers), i.e. by means of a distance to the origin $|z|$ and an angle $\arg z$ relative to the positive real axis.  Then due to (1) we have
$$z = |z|\cdot e^{i\arg z}
= |z|\cdot e^{i\arg z+2\pi i k} \tag{2}
$$
where you have the freedom to chose an integer $k\in\Bbb Z$.  This is because an angle (here: the one relative to the positive real axis) is only determined modulo $2\pi$ (which is modulo $360^\circ$).

Equation (2) allows to define a Natural Logarithm over the non-zero complex numbers as
$$
\ln z = \ln|z| + i\arg z + 2\pi i\cdot k
$$
However, due to the ambiguity in $k$, this is **not a function**! To make it a proper function, you have to fix one specific $k$, and you have to specify how angles are defined in order to give arg a meaning, for example $\arg z\in[0,2\pi)$ or $\arg z\in[-\pi,\pi)$ or whatever.  Then, a functions you get for a specific choice of $k$ is called **a branch of the (complex) logarithm** with the most common one usually called *main branch* or *principle branch* with the choices $k=0$ and $\arg\in(-\pi,\pi]$$.  The latter condition is often referred to as "where the cut (of ln) is made" or "cutting ln along the negative real axis", see [branch cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point#Branch_cuts).

You can now extend this from $\ln$ to $\log_{10}$.

This means you can make sense of $\log_{10}(-1)$, and whatever branch configuration you will be using, a characteristic property will always be that
$$10^{\log_{10}(-1)} = -1$$